# The simplification of divided difference of cosine function

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

What is the following limit?

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\cos(\pi/2+h)-\cos(\pi/2)}{h}$$

Why when simplified do you get $(-\sin(h))/h)$?

Comment: Because $\cos \pi/2 = 0$ and $\cos(\pi/2 + h) = -\sin h$

Comment: Just make a drawing. This formula is part of the basics in trigonometry.

Comment: If your question is about how to manipulate a trigonometric expression, you shouldn't give it a title and tags that trick the reader into thinking you need help with limits.

Comment: Also, consider that this site has over 11000 questions about limits in calculus, and try to give yours a more specific title than "calculus limit question".

Answer (score 2):

A cosine wave is just a sine wave shifted to the left by $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so use the following trig identity:

$$\cos(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin(\theta + \pi) = -\sin(\theta)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \cos\left(A+B\right) = \cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)$$ $$\Downarrow$$ $$ \dfrac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+h\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{h} \ = \ \dfrac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cos(h)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sin(h)}{h} \ = \ \dfrac{-\sin(h)}{h}$$

Answer (score -1):

you know :$$cos(a+b)=cos a cos b -sin a sin b\\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)=cos(\frac{\pi}{2})cos h - sin (\frac{\pi}{2}) sin h=0 -1* sin h$$
use this to find that limit 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)-cos \frac{\pi}{2}}{h}=\\\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-1*sin h-cos \frac{\pi}{2}}{h}=\\\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-1*sin h-0}{h}$$